# Why does pandas.Series.replace() have different functionality between versions?

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**: `pandas.Series.replace()` successfully replaces `bool` values to floats in version `0.24.2`.  Running the same lines of code in version `1.1.3` produces a different result.

**Example Code**:

Using `0.24.2`:

```
import pandas
pd.__version__ # 0.24.2
a = pd.Series([True, False, False, True])
a
```

```
0  True
1  False
2  False
3  True
dtype: bool
```

```
a.replace(True, 1.2).replace(False, 1)
```

```
0   1.2
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.2
dtype: float64
```

Using `1.1.3`:

```
import pandas
pd.__version__ # 1.1.3
a = pd.Series([True, False, False, True])
a
```

```
0  True
1  False
2  False
3  True
dtype: bool
```

```
a.replace(True, 1.2).replace(False, 1)
```

```
0   1.2
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   1.2
dtype: float64
```

I also tried similar syntax to what I found here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/6339, but that results in something different.

```
a.replace({True: 1.2, False: 1})
```

```
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
dtype: float64
```

I'm able to change it successfully using the code below, but haven't found anything about the functionality changing.  The additional `.astype(int)` seems unnecessary.

```
a.astype(int).replace({1: 1.2, 0: 1})
```

```
0   1.2
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.2
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

No backward compatibility is kind of expected for major releases (0.xx vs 1.xx). In fact, development releases (0.xx) don't guarantee backward compatibility even for minor and patch releases.

[Semantic versioning](https://semver.org):

> Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backwards
> incompatible changes are introduced to the public API. It MAY also
> include minor and patch level changes. Patch and minor version MUST be
> reset to 0 when major version is incremented.